# How can I disable comments when using the YouTube Python API?

Tags: python, youtube-api

We've already disabled comments in YouTube channel settings, but users can still add comments to videos that are uploaded automatically via the API. How can I disable comments when using the YouTube Python API?

Comment: welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Edit your question, include your code. show the section of the documentation where it states what you are trying to do is possible.

Comment: Help track and vote for this feature: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174729